# Stuck in "grub rescue" after partial uninstall of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, uninstall

I have a Windows 8 laptop that I installed an Ubuntu partition on. I am going to donate this laptop and so was trying to uninstall Ubuntu.  In the middle of it the laptop rebooted and now it starts up with `grub rescue`.  I have tried many commands, but because all but one partition (zero size) is gone it won't take any of the commands.  Any advice?

I've got a Windows 8 rescue disk so I could try to fix the boot order, but the laptop will not boot from it.  Is there a grub command to boot from the CD?

Comment: Have you checked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on ?